# Having a urxvt "sticky shell" with fluxbox?

Tags: linux, urxvt, fluxbox

I am trying to have a shell bound to a key, on my gentoo fluxbox. The idea is having a shell that would show or hide each time I press `F11`, but keeping the same shell, not creating a new one each time.

For now, I somehow managed to do it.

I've inserted I my `.fluxbox/keys` :

```
F11 :ExecCommand /home/me/script/toogle-sticky-shell
```

where the called script is simply :

```
##!/bin/sh
pid=$(ps -ef | grep surxv | head -n -1 | head -c 14 | tail -c 5)
if [ $pid ]
    kill $pid
else
    urxvt -name surxvt -e screen -RD StickyShell &
fi
```

And adapted my `.fluxbox/apps` with :

```
[app] (name=surxvt)
  [Hidden]  {yes}
  [Layer]   {2}
  [Position]    (WINCENTER) {0 0}
  [Deco]    {BORDER}
  [Tab]     {no}
  [FocusNewWindow] {yes}
  [Sticky]  {yes}
[end]
```

So basically, in order to keep my shell alive, I'm using `screen`. But I feel like it's not a 'clean' solution.

So my question is : Is there a cleaner way to achieve this ?

For example, is it possible to selectively hide/show a window with fluxbox by pressing a key ?

Comment: Do you mean to ask if a window can be minimized with a fluxbox command from shell script (or ~/.fluxbox/keys)? Something more exotic? Do you need the shell to stay alive after fluxbox dies?

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин if a fluxbox command in `.fluxbox/keys` can minimize or maximize a particular window, it would be exactly what I'm looking for, and hadn't found so far. I don't care whether the shell dies or not with fluxbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install wmctrl

   ```
   x11-misc/wmctrl
     Homepage:     http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/
     Description:  command line tool to interact with an EWMH/NetWM compatible
                   X Window Manager
   ```
2. Start a "named" terminal

   `urxvt -name moo`
3. Write your toggle-minimize script using

   `wmctrl -x -r moo.URxvt  -b toggle,hidden`
4. and call if from the keys file.

   `F11 :ExecCommand /home/me/script/toogle-hidden moo`

If you need more tips, I'll be glad to help.

---

By the way, I don't think your previous approach is bad. Apart from the way you find the pid and some caveats of screen (non-critical), there is nothing wrong with it.

---

update:

The screen draw-back is not really an issue because you can do scrolling (in copy mode, by pressing ^A + [) and because X can be reached by setting DISPLAY. Some people will have you believe that `tmux` is the next best thing to enlightenment, but I tend to write them off as I do with the zsh zealots...

The other thing is unsound because you look for the pid at specific string offsets (head -c) and because the grep keyword is bound to give you a wrong pid (several lines) at some point. for example:

```
$ ps -ef | grep moo
jaroslav 20089     1  0 Jul23 ?       00:00:00 SCREEN -dR moo
jaroslav 26545 26420  0 08:21 pts/10  00:00:01 rxvt-unicode -name moo
jaroslav 27702 26981  0 08:52 pts/12  00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/cowsay moo
jaroslav 27704 26771  0 08:52 pts/7   00:00:00 grep --colour=auto moo
```

This would kill the screen and not the terminal emulator. It's "unsafe" to pre-suppose that ps produces a specific amount of lines or that some colums are of a given width (I think you assumed 3 lines with headers and 14 characters for the first two columns).

I'd go with something like this instead:

```
ps `pidof rxvt-unicode` | grep -m1 -e '-nam[e] moo' | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

or

```
ps ax  | awk '$0 ~ /rxvt-unicode.*-nam[e] moo/ {print $1; exit}'
```

With both of these, at least I'm fairly certain that the pid belongs to a rxvt terminal that it was started with -name moo as two of its arguments. And absolutely sure that the output will have at most one pid. The -nam[e] is an old trick to avoid matching the `ps | grep` command  in the output.

All this is nitpicking... The rules of thumb are.

1. don't assume output of a program to be x chars wide or y lines long.
2. long regular expressions (more strict) are almost always better than short ones.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. I guess with `wmctrl -l` I'll be able to handle the situations where I killed the shell by mistake (`^D` comes so easily..). Just being curious, how may the things you mention be improved in my approach ?